# Storing a result set to use in a different class

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have the working prepared statement here:

```
public boolean requestBuy(int user_id, String broker_name, String company_name, int shares, String comments)
    {
        ....
        ....
                pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO broker_requests VALUES" +
                                                "(br_request_id_increment.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                pstmnt.setInt(1, user_id);
                pstmnt.setString(2, broker_name);
                pstmnt.setString(3, "Buy");
                pstmnt.setInt(4, shares);
                pstmnt.setString(5, company_name);
                pstmnt.setString(6, comments);
                pstmnt.executeQuery();

                logger.info("Request Share Purchase: " + company_name + " has requested to purchase " + shares + " from" + company_name);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is store the result set into different variables (or maybe an arrayList?) in order to use those values in a different class. Any ideas?

Comment: You're executing a `INSERT` statement, so you won't have a `ResultSet`. Probably you want to provide a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using a map, a key-value pair will help you store and retrieve the column names and value in a logical manner.

or

Simply create a class representing your database data and create and populate an instance(s) of it.

Comment: I heavily discourage `Map` approach. It becomes a hell for maintenance purposes.

Comment: @surfealokesea you probably mean ORM frameworks and Hibernate is an example of them.